# Two Different Jquery Javascript Codes Not working on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two codes on one page first one is used to store the last state of drop down menu and second one is to post data. But These are not working on one page. But when I try these code on individual pages it works fine. I am new one. Thanks in Advance.

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cookie = $.cookie("panelState"),
    expanded = cookie ? cookie.split("|").getUnique() : [],
    cookieExpires = 7; // cookie expires in 7 days, or set this as a date object to specify a date

    // show cookie content


    // Remember content that was expanded
    $.each( expanded, function(){
        $('#' + this).show();
    })

    $('li.primary').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        $(this).next().slideToggle('300', function(){
            updateCookie(this);
        });
    })

    // Update the Cookie
    function updateCookie(el){
        var indx = el.id;
        var tmp = expanded.getUnique();
        if ($(el).is(':hidden')) {
            // remove element id from the list
            tmp.splice( tmp.indexOf(el.id) , 1);
        } else {
            // add index of widget to expanded list
            tmp.push(el.id);
        }
        expanded = tmp.getUnique();
        $.cookie("panelState", expanded.join('|'), { expires: cookieExpires } );


    }
});

// Return a unique array.
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(sort){
    var u = {}, a = [], i, l = this.length;
    for(i = 0; i < l; ++i){
        if(this[i] in u) { continue; }
        a.push(this[i]);
        u[this[i]] = 1;
    }
    return (sort) ? a.sort() : a;
}








    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loading_show(){
    $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
}
function loading_hide(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
}                
function loadData(page,qu,name){
    loading_show();                    
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "urlbodies/editmembercomloaddata.php",
        data: "page="+page+"&qu="+qu+"&name="+name,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                loading_hide();
                $("#container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}




$('#pressbutton').live('click',function(){
    var qu = $('#commiteename').val();
    var name = $('#txtBox').val();
    loadData(1,qu,name);


}); 




loadData(1,"All","");  // For first time page load default results
$('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('p');
    var qu = $('#commiteename').val();
    var name = $('#txtBox').val();
    loadData(page,qu,name);


});           
$('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
        var qu = $('#commiteename').val();
        var name = $('#txtBox').val();
        loadData(page,qu,name);
    }else{
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val("").focus();
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: why < script type = "text/javascript" > ?

Comment: Try this code http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/Mh9dT/

Comment: if i remove text/javascript then also its not working

Comment: have you tried JS code in the link i paste here ?

Comment: I fixed your JS code.But i don't know it usage .There is no syntax errors now

Comment: yes now second code that is used for post the data is working but the frist code is not working yet

Comment: Perhaps you should consider taking the `<script>` tag out of the middle of the script and putting it at the top, before any of your javascript. And then end it with `</script>`